Dynamic allocation of array integer within C++ struct
I am trying to wrap a dynamic integer array in a struct as below.
#include <iostream>

struct dynamic_int_array {
    int *ptr;
    size_t n;
    dynamic_int_array():ptr(NULL),n(0){};
    void insert(int x) {
        n++;
        ptr=(int *)realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*n);
        *(ptr+sizeof(int)*(n-1))=x;
    }
    int tail() {
        return(*(ptr+sizeof(int)*(n-1)));
    }
};
int main(void) {
    dynamic_int_array a;
    for(int i{0};i<100000;i++) {
        a.insert(i);
        std::cout<<a.tail()<<' ';
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
}

The result of running this is a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" and from reading other related posts I know this means that I am either not (re-)allocating the right way, or not releasing memory where I should be.
My question is what correction does this programme need to run as expected? Thank you.

Using realloc in C++ is always wrong. Now if you don't even know which programming language you are using, then it's super hard to write any working line of code.

What do you think (ptr+sizeof(int)*(n-1)) evaluates to given that ptr is of type int *?

Why not just use std::vector<int>?

You might want to read How to debug small programs and What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?.

*(ptr+sizeof(int)*(n-1))=x should be *(ptr+n-1)=x or more simply ptr[n-1]=x

@Lundin, thanks for the correction, I was trying to emphasise that I was using a C struct, but that is incorrect since I have a member function in there. Would you please elaborate on the usage of realloc in C++, is it unsupported and therefore leads to unexpected no-guarantee results?

@G.M. Thanks, when the length of an integer is 4 bytes, that would be the last (integer) element in the (expanded) array, I was hoping?

@AlanBirtles Thank you, this might be what G.M. was getting at too. it seems like you are saying we don't need to account in bytes, but can use whatever unit is implied by the declaration of the pointer (int *ptr, so integer) above. Let me try that.

@G.M. thank you, you identified the problem right away.

@Psmith malloc/realloc/free etc do not call constructors/destructors, unlike new/delete. In C++, structs have constructors/destructors. In C they do not.

Thanks @Lundin, yes, I am aware of new and delete operations, even if I fall back on the malloc cohort due to my own familiarity with it. Is the guidance to stop using those as they are not supported?

malloc, calloc, free, etc. are fully supported in C++.  The issue is that it is not recommended to use them, and especially not incorrectly.  Ideally you should be using std::vector anyway -- that's what it is there for, to create a dynamic array.

@PaulMcKenzie, thank you for the definitive answer to my question on compatibility. Aside, since it was also asked before in the commetns,, my intention was to use realloc correctly and I felt that turning to std::vector would not have satisfied that intention entirely.
